# Receiving payload along with ancillary data in transmit timestamp packets in linux socket

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I'm trying to do transmit hardware timestamping on my packets according to the [Linux documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/timestamping.txt)
As it says, the timestamped packet is transmitted back to the errorQueue without any modification so I should see my payload data back in there BUT I can't.
I put a unique ID in my payload to identify each packet, but it is shown empty when I receive it in errorQueue.
So the question is: **Why am I not receiving my payload in errorQueue along with the ancillary data (which has the hardware timestamps I requested)**
I have added a part of my code that is relevant and I hope somebody can help.
Thanks in advance.

```
while (1) {

    make_address(0, &remote);
    iov.iov_base = buffer;
    iov.iov_len = 2048;
    msg.msg_iov = &iov;
    msg.msg_iovlen = 1;
    msg.msg_name = &remote;
    msg.msg_namelen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    msg.msg_control = control;
    msg.msg_controllen = 1024;

    send_iov.iov_base = send_buffer;
    send_iov.iov_len = 2048;
    sendm.msg_iov = &send_iov;
    sendm.msg_iovlen = 1;
    sendm.msg_name = &remote;
    sendm.msg_namelen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    sendm.msg_control = 0;
    sendm.msg_controllen = 0;

    iov2.iov_base = buffer2;
    iov2.iov_len = 4096;
    msg2.msg_iov = &iov2;
    msg2.msg_iovlen = 1;
    msg2.msg_name = &remote;
    msg2.msg_namelen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    msg2.msg_control = control;
    msg2.msg_controllen = 1024;


    FD_ZERO(&readfs);
    FD_ZERO(&errorfs);
    FD_SET(sock, &readfs);
    FD_SET(sock, &errorfs);
    delta.tv_sec = 5;
    delta.tv_usec = 0;
    /* read a datagram from the socket (put result in bufin) */
    res = select(sock + 1, &readfs, 0, &errorfs, &delta);

    n = (int) recvmsg(sock, &msg, MSG_DONTWAIT);
    if (n >= 0) {
        char* temp = msg.msg_iov[0].iov_base;
        printf("REQ %s \n", temp);
        char* sss = handle_time(&msg,1);

        sscanf(temporary_char_array, "%d", uid); // add Unique ID
        msg.msg_iov[0].iov_base = temporary_char_array;
        uid++;

        f = (int) sendmsg(sock, &msg, 0);
        free(sss);
    }

    n = (int) recvmsg(sock, &msg2, MSG_DONTWAIT | MSG_ERRQUEUE);
    if (n >= 0) {
      char* temp = msg2.msg_iov->iov_base;
      printf("RES %s \n", temp);    // I read empty string here. Why??

      handle_time(&msg2,2);
    }
}
```

Comment: `res = select(sock + 1, &readfs, 0, &errorfs, &delta);` Check the return value `res`. In your case It can be {-1,0,1}

Answer (score 0):

Well, looks like the problem is the way I wanted to print out the receive buffer, so instead of using `"%s"` in `printf` , I tried:

```
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
    printf("%c", buffer2[i]);
```

And this revealed the buffer for me. There were some anonymous data at the beginning of the buffer which caused the problem.
There is are documentation or examples in this area I'm afraid.